# Math.ceil in js calculation

Tags: javascript

I don't get the `Math.ceil` to work with my current js code. I thought it has to be right after `toFixed`, but that's not working unfortunately.

The result of the calculation should be cut down to 2 decimals and uprounded with `Math.ceil` when a decimal place shows up.

How do I get that done?

```js
function output() {
  var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = ((parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(value2)) / parseFloat(value3)).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> / </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h081aq3c/

Comment: Can you post an example (use case) where the result is not what you want, and show us the expected result of that example.

Comment: at line 18 is the change: https://jsfiddle.net/h081aq3c/1/

Comment: Alex show us an example where your code doesn't give the expected result (What should we type in the inputs above to get that wrong result? And what should the right result be?) As the wording of the question is not clear.

Comment: already solved, figured it out. Thanks anyway. The Math.ceil was at the wrong place